# How to make a JSP function to run only when called?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I'm having a JSP page as follows :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Admin Tools</title>
        <jsp:include page="/basic/nav.jsp"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tools.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Admin Tools</h2>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
            <%
                boolean def_admin = false, def_admin_changed = false;
                conn.connect.main(null);
                conn.dbc.main(null);
                ResultSet rstools = conn.connect.st.executeQuery("select * from admins where uname='admin'");
                if (rstools.next()) {
                    if (rstools.getString("uname").equals("admin") && rstools.getString("password").equals("123")) {
                        def_admin = true;
                    }
                    if (rstools.getString("uname").equals("admin") && !rstools.getString("password").equals("123")) {
                        def_admin_changed = true;
                    }
               }
            %>
            <%if (def_admin == false) {%>
            Add Default Admin Account :<br/>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="<% add_admin(); %>"/>
            <% } else if (def_admin == true && def_admin_changed == false) { %>
            Delete Default Admin Account :<br/>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="<% delete_admin(); %>"/>
            <% } else if (def_admin == true && def_admin_changed == false) { %>
            The Default Admin Password Exists but the password has been changed<br/>
        Do you still want to delete the Default Admin Account?<br/>
            <input type="button" value="Even so, Delete it" onclick="<% delete_admin(); %>"/>
        <% }%>

        <div id="tools_error"></div>

        <%!
            boolean insert_success = false;

            void add_admin() {
                try {
                    int Urows;
                    Urows = conn.connect.st.executeUpdate("insert into admins(uname,password) values('admin','123');");
                    if (Urows == 1) {
                        insert_success = true;
                    } else {
                        insert_success = false;
                    }
        %>
            <script>
            (function () {
                boolean i_s = "<%=insert_success%>";
                if (i_s == false) {
                    document.getElementById("tools_error").value = "There has been an error in Adding Default Admin";
                }
            });
            </script>
            <%!
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                void delete_admin() {

                }
            %>
        </div>
    </body>
    <jsp:include page="/basic/footer.jsp"/>
</html>
```

As you can see when the button is clicked I have made it to run the declared JSP functions. But when the JSP file is loaded the functions run automatically and the insert MYSQL query runs which automatically inserts the values given in the query.

I don't want it the functions `add_admin()` and `delete_admin()` to run automatically on load. Any suggestions?

Comment: don't write code in your jsp, write a proper servlet that will execute code before presenting the JSP via RequestDispatcher

Comment: @BigMike I don't think the question here is "should I use servlets over jsp". Unless you're saying that there is no way to do that in jsp, in which case I miscomprehended.

Comment: You're kinda right I could've expressed it better, main issue here is the confusion between server and client side code execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events in the webpage (onclick event for example) is executed client side when someone opens your webpage and clicks the button. The JSP scriplets are executed when the webpage is opened and their result is the actual page that the client receives. So your method executes ONLY when the page is loaded (and the JSP is compiled). The java code is not even visible in the webpage you generate. If you open it in browser and check the source you will see what I mean.

Comment: So I guess i have no choice but to put it in a servlet/java file. As you can see in the code, I just wanted the script to be in the middle of the JSP that's all is the reason I decided to put it in the JSP.

Comment: Thanks anyway, now that I know it not possible on JSP, I can find my own solution :)

Comment: Yes in order to execute something in the backend (JSP/servlet or whatever) You will need to do a request from the webpage. You can use JSP and not a servlet. JSP is basically a servlet - just written in a pretty fashion. For example if we take the delete button and make it onClick=window.location.search += '&delete=true' you can then use <% String delete = request.getParameter("delete"); %> and do the logic accordingly. But it will be the same - each button will reload the page and recompile the java code with different parameter

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: You can't**

Your Java code is executed once, when the page is loaded. The page is not on the server anymore, so you can't use its back-end capabilities. Otherwise, that would mean someone reewriting your HTML could make your page execute any code on your back-end.

Once your page is loaded, all there is on it is HTML and Javascript (CSS if you want to bicker).